# Unable to locate exception in Application start method

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, stage, fxmlloader

Could someone please take a look at my code? It all worked fine yesterday, but it seems like I somehow made a small change that brakes the code. Unfortunately I am not able to find it.

This is the error I get while compiling:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\rezagholifa\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Uhren Konfiguration" jfxsa-run
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\src\core\FXMLDocumentController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 3 files to C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\dist
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 12 files to C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\dist\run714342489
jfx-project-run:
Executing C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\dist\run714342489\Uhren Konfiguration.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/rezagholifa/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Uhren%20Konfiguration/dist/run714342489/Uhren%20Konfiguration.jar!/core/FXMLDocument.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at core.Main.start(Main.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:211)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application core.Main
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\rezagholifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Uhren Konfiguration\dist\run714342489
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

This is the structure of my program:

```
src
  core
     FXMLDocument
     FXMLDocumentController
     Main.java
  img
     icon.png
     logo.png
```

---

**FXMLDocument:**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="core.FXMLDocumentController">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Datei">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#aboutAction" text="Über">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="F1" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quitAction" text="Beenden">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="F4" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Funktionen">
                    <items>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ziel-Uhren">
                            <items>
                                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="clockMenuItem1" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Mechanik">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="DIGIT1" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </CheckMenuItem>
                                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="clockMenuItem2" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Elektronik">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="DIGIT2" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </CheckMenuItem>
                                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="clockMenuItem3" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Werkstatt">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="DIGIT3" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </CheckMenuItem>
                                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="clockMenuItem4" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Schulungsraum">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="DIGIT4" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </CheckMenuItem>
                                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="clockMenuItem5" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Aufenthaltsraum">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="DIGIT5" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </CheckMenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getTimeAction" text="Hole Zeit von PC">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="T" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Update..." />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <ImageView pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <image>
                <Image url="@../img/logo.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <Accordion BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <panes>
                <TitledPane contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Nachricht" underline="true" wrapText="true">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                            <children>
                                <TextArea fx:id="messageTextArea1" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Nachricht">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 45 Light" size="12.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <opaqueInsets>
                                        <Insets />
                                    </opaqueInsets>
                                </TextArea>
                                <Button layoutX="24.0" layoutY="94.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#messageAction" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Nachricht anzeigen!" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 57 Condensed" size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Button>
                                <TextArea fx:id="timeTextArea1" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Anzeigedauer [in Sekunden]">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 45 Light" size="12.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <opaqueInsets>
                                        <Insets />
                                    </opaqueInsets>
                                </TextArea>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Zeit" underline="true" wrapText="true">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                            <children>
                                <TextArea fx:id="hourTextArea1" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="93.0" promptText="Stunde">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 45 Light" size="12.0" />
                                    </font>
                                    <opaqueInsets>
                                        <Insets />
                                    </opaqueInsets>
                                </TextArea>
                                <TextArea fx:id="minuteTextArea1" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="93.0" promptText="Minute">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 45 Light" size="12.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </TextArea>
                                <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="117.0" layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="14.0" style="&#10;" text=":" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="false">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font size="18.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Button layoutX="24.0" layoutY="72.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#timeAction" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Zeit einstellen!" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 57 Condensed" size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Button>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Farbe" underline="true" wrapText="true">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                            <children>
                                <ChoiceBox fx:id="colorChoiceBox1" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="29.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                <Button layoutX="24.0" layoutY="69.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#colorAction" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Farbe einstellen!" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 57 Condensed" size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Button>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Lautstärke" underline="true" wrapText="true">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                            <children>
                                <Button layoutX="24.0" layoutY="67.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#volumeAction" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Lautstärke einstellen!" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                    <font>
                                        <Font name="Frutiger LT Com 57 Condensed" size="14.0" />
                                    </font>
                                </Button>
                                <Slider fx:id="volumeSlider1" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="23.0" majorTickUnit="20.0" minorTickCount="10" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="205.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" value="50.0" />
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
            </panes>
        </Accordion>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

**FXMLDocumentController:**

```
package core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    ObservableList<String> colorsObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Rot", "Orange", "Grün");

    public static String versionString = "v1.3.1";

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox colorChoiceBox;

    @FXML
    private Slider volumeSlider;

    @FXML
    private TextArea hourTextArea;

    @FXML
    private TextArea minuteTextArea;

    @FXML
    private TextArea messageTextArea;

    @FXML
    private TextArea timeTextArea;

    @FXML
    private CheckMenuItem clockMenuItem1;

    @FXML
    private CheckMenuItem clockMenuItem2;

    @FXML
    private CheckMenuItem clockMenuItem3;

    @FXML
    private CheckMenuItem clockMenuItem4;

    @FXML
    private CheckMenuItem clockMenuItem5;

    @FXML
    private void messageAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        try {
            int t = Integer.parseInt(timeTextArea.getText());
            if ((t > 0 && t <= 36000) && (messageTextArea.getText().length() != 0)) {
                System.out.println("TBI - Message");
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Bestätigung");
                alert.setHeaderText("Nachricht versendet!");
                alert.setContentText("Das Paket wurde erfolgreich versendet :)");
                alert.showAndWait();
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            messageTextArea.setText("");
            timeTextArea.setText("");
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Fehler!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten");
            alert.setContentText("Bei der Umwandlung der Eingaben ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.\nHaben Sie unzulässige Zeichen eingegeben?\nDer Maximalwert für den Timer beträgt 36000.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void timeAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        try {
            // check if input can be converted to int
            int h = Integer.parseInt(hourTextArea.getText());
            int m = Integer.parseInt(minuteTextArea.getText());
            // check if both integers are not longer than two digits, that h is
            // smaller or equal 12 and that m is smaller than or equal 59
            if ((Integer.toString(h).length() <= 2 && Integer.toString(m).length() <= 2) && (h <= 24 && m <= 59)) {
                //System.out.println(hour.getText() + ":" + minute.getText());
                broadcast(h, m);
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Bestätigung");
                alert.setHeaderText("Zeit gestellt!");
                alert.setContentText("Das Paket wurde erfolgreich versendet :)");
                alert.showAndWait();
            } else {
                // throw RuntimeException if the input could not be converted
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            //reset input values
            hourTextArea.setText("");
            minuteTextArea.setText("");
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Fehler!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten");
            alert.setContentText("Bei der Umwandlung der Eingaben ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.\nHaben Sie unzulässige Zeichen eingegeben?");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void aboutAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Über");
        alert.setHeaderText("AG Uhrzeit stellen");
        alert.setContentText("Dises Programm sendet auf Port 12345 einen UDP-Broadcast, nach dem alle Uhren in der AG neu gestellt werden.\n\nVersion:\t" + versionString + "\n\nCopyright © 2016");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    private void getTimeAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        hourTextArea.setText("");
        minuteTextArea.setText("");
        hourTextArea.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        minuteTextArea.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }

    @FXML
    private void beepAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("TBI - Beep");
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Bestätigung");
        alert.setHeaderText("Beep wird abgespielt!");
        alert.setContentText("Das Paket wurde erfolgreich versendet :)");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    private void marioAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("TBI - Mario");
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Bestätigung");
        alert.setHeaderText("Mario Theme wird abgespielt!");
        alert.setContentText("Das Paket wurde erfolgreich versendet :)");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    private void colorAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("TBI - >Color");
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Bestätigung");
        alert.setHeaderText("Farbe eingestellt!");
        alert.setContentText("Das Paket wurde erfolgreich versendet :)");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    private void volumeAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("TBI - >Volume");
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Bestätigung");
        alert.setHeaderText("Lautstärke eingestellt!");
        alert.setContentText("Das Paket wurde erfolgreich versendet :)");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    // TODO
    public static void broadcast(int h, int m) throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = null;
        try {
            datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String test = h + ":" + m;
        byte[] buffer = test.getBytes();
        InetAddress receiverAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, receiverAddress, 80);
        datagramSocket.send(packet);
    }

    @FXML
    private void quitAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        colorChoiceBox.setValue("Rot");
        colorChoiceBox.setItems(colorsObservableList);
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**
    package core;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static String appTitle = "Uhren Konfiguration";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle(appTitle);
        //stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("img/icon.png"));
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: we are also unable to find your `Exception` without your Error `StackTrace` @farosch

Comment: You're absolutely right guys, just added it. sorry about that - I don't know where my head is at today..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` in `FXMLDocumentController.initialize` line 211

Comment: I already did check that line. It's 'colorChoiceBox.setValue("Rot");' which is perfectly fine and worked earlier but while using SceneBuilder I must have somehow accidently changed the fxid to 'colorChoiceBoxcgzk'.
No wonder it didn't work..
As I said, today is not my day...

Thank you ALOT!
Now everything works again :)

I somehow have the feeling an exception like this should throw a more informative error